# Accessing Windows files from Ubuntu live

Tags: boot, windows

My Windows PC had a booting problem out of nowhere this morning, where it constantly asked for a proper booting device despite showing all my disks including the one with OS at BIOS. Tried every possible fix on the net but got nowhere and im struggling with this for 6 hours straight now that i don't even understand what i read. So I set up an Ubuntu on an usb and boot a live version to save my files so i could format the disk but i can't get to access my disks. They don't show up on the file browser. They do show up on the console with `sudo fdisk -l` but only at top, not at the bottom where it shows partitions i guess ? They only show as /sda /sdb, not as /sda1 /sdb2. So i can't use the guides on web to save my files as they need the ones with numbers. Is there anything I'm doing wrong or did the disks fail ? I'm really sorry about the grammar mistakes as English is not my native language and im really tired. Also I would really appreciate any help about the booting problem too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows fast boot option will make ubuntu not see disks or if ubuntu does see disks/files it is dangerous to touch them.  This is mainly for Windows from 8 on.  Also need to know if windows is loaded by BIOS or UEFI.

Comment: @crip659 I have Windows 10 which should be loaded by BIOS. My disks doesn't even show up when i select boot option as UEFI instead of UEFI + Legacy.

Comment: Using two OSs on one computer, they should both be booted the same, UEFI or legacy.  Win 10 is usually UEFI boot.  Not sure but think ubuntu live USBs can be set/burned as UEFI or legacy depending on burner program.  You might need a Windows repair disk if windows in fast boot shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've got nothing related to Ubuntu here but if anyone experiences the same booting problem, I managed to solve it after straight 12 hours trying and i guess i don't need to mention how accomplished I feel now :D. Well, I booted the PC with this [Hiren's Boot](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/)
thingy and stumbled upon something when looking around. All I had to do was changing my disks' format back to GPT from MBR. I have no idea how they get to MBR in the first place. I haven't seen that as a fix anywhere so if you tried everything and couldn't solve the "reboot and insert a proper boot device" problem give this a shot. Also sorry for polluting the Ubuntu board with this but i hope this will do good for someone.

Comment: Glad you could fix it.  Can always play with the Ubuntu live USB now.